# Retrieve datetime object in Powershell without the time portion

Tags: powershell, datetime

Is it possible to retrieve only the date portion of a datetime object in PowerShell? Reason being I need to compare the `LastWriteTime` property of files with today's date to determine whether to backup a file or not. As-is a datetime object includes the time as well which will always evaluate to false when I do something like:

```
if ($fileDate -eq $currentDate) {
    # Do backup
}
```

I haven't found anyway to do this. If we use the format operator or a method, it converts the object to a string object. If you try to convert that back to a datetime object, it appends the time back onto the object. Probably something simple, but I've been looking at this script for a while and that's the last part that's breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not answer how to remove time on datetime, but to do your validation purpose of identifying when to backup.

I do suggest to subtract your two given date values and compare the result if total hours are already met to do your backup.

```
if (( $currentDate - $fileDate ).TotalDays > 7) {
# Do Backup
}
```

you can also validate for the following

```
Days              : 
Hours             : 
Minutes           : 
Seconds           : 
Milliseconds      : 
Ticks             :
TotalDays         : 
TotalHours        : 
TotalMinutes      : 
TotalSeconds      : 
TotalMilliseconds :
```

Comment: I'll accept this one. Looks like I can use the .TotalDays -eq 0 comparison to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** As @jessehouwing points out in the comments below, my answers are unnecessarily complicated.  Just use `$datetime.Date`.

---

A couple of ways to get a DateTime without any time component (ie set to midnight at the start of the date in question, 00:00:00):

```
$dateTime = <some DateTime>
$dateWithoutTime = $dateTime.AddSeconds(-$dateTime.Second).AddMinutes(-$dateTime.Minute).AddHours(-$dateTime.Hour)
```

or

```
$dateTime = <some DateTime>
$dateWithoutTime = Get-Date -Date ($dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

I ran each version in a loop, iterating 100,000 times.  The first version took 16.4 seconds, the second version took 26.5 seconds.  So I would go with the first version, although it looks a little more complicated.

Based on answers found here: https://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-how-to-query-date-time-without-seconds/2737 (that article is about stripping just the seconds from a DateTime.  But it can be extended to stripping hours, minutes and seconds).

Comment: Why not just take `(Get-Date).Date`

Comment: @jessehouwing: I was assuming that the DateTime being operated on could be any DateTime, not necessarily DateTime.Now.  I just set $dateTime to Get-Date for convenience.  I'll edit the examples to remove it, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Any DateTime you can call the Date property on. If not, it's not a DateTime.

Comment: @jessehouwing: Of course, thanks for pointing that out.  No need for complicated work-arounds in PowerShell!

Comment: In the spirit of Jesse's comment, you can also just leverage:
`Get-Date -DisplayHint Date` . Link to Microsoft Doc for the cmd [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.4#example-2-get-elements-of-the-current-date-and-time)

Comment: @JohnnyWelker: Thanks for that.  I had assumed `-DisplayHint` was a bit like `.ToString()` with a format string - that it would return a string not a DateTime.  However, when I tried  `(get-date -displayhint Date).GetType().FullName` it said the output type is `System.DateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `$currentTime` contains a DateTime object, you can retrieve a new DateTime object with the same date but with the time portion zeroed like this:

```
$midnight = Get-Date $currentTime -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $fileDate is not a dateTime object, then you can just convert both to strings and format them.

```
if ($fileDate.ToString() -eq $currentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) {
    # Do backup
}
```